# Cannot bind complex type data list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, complex-data-types

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I am working with complex data in my application. Now I am trying to bind ViewModel that has a property of collection of complex data type. I followed this link http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/. But my code is not working.

**View model**:

```
 public class EditItemSelectsVM
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Select> Selects { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Belonging> Belongings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Select
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MmName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string MmDescription { get; set; }
        public int RowId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Belonging
    {
        public string BelongingName { get; set; }
        public string BelongingMmName { get; set; }
        public int BelongTo { get; set; }
    }
```

`EditItemSelectsVM` class is the view model

To test the binding work or not, I created a test form and submitted the form.

**Html**:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].RowId" />
           <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                     <label>Name</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-7">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="[0].Name" />
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-5">
                     <label>MM Name</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-7">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="[0].MmName" />
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label>Description</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-7">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="[0].Description" />
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                 <label>MM Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="[0].MmDescription" />
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Above html is to bind `IEnumerable<Select> Selects` in view model. But when I submit the form, `IEnumerable<Select> Selects` is always null. How can I fix it?

Comment: It needs to be `name="Selects[0].Name"` but why in the world are you doing this manually (it will fail for lots of other reasons). Bind to a model using a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Hi @Wai Yan , I think this is because you need to refer to your viewModel `Selects`.

Comment: What do u mean using for loop? My html code is just to demonstrate. I am using for loop and set the index with the counter. U mean that ?@stephen

Comment: You cannot be using a `for` loop because your property is `IEnumerable<T>` - and if you were it would be generating the correct `name` attributes anyway. Suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked.How can I bind if select is something like this public class Select
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MmName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string MmDescription { get; set; }
        public int RowId { get; set; } public IEnumerable<Belonging> Belongings{get ;set; }
    }

Comment: Please can u guide me a link? @StephenMuecke

Comment: @WaiYanHein, Refer the link in my last comment. If the collection property is `IEnumerable<T>` (rather that `IList<T>`), then you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for `T`

Comment: Thanks. I got it worked.